# Representations of triangle groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$I am self-studying triangle groups and the following question comes up.

Let $G$ denotes $(2,3,7)$ triangle group. It is symmetry group of $(2,3,7)$ tiling of the hyperbolic plane. The group of orientation-preserving automorphisms of the Poincare disc model of the hyperbolic plane is $\SU_2(1,1)$. Now if we consider the orientation preserving part of $G$ then it is a subgroup of $\SU_2(1,1)$.

Now suppose we have an element of $\SU_2(1,1)$ say $A$. Can we get some conditions on the entries of $A$ for $A$ belongs to the orientation preserving part of $G$ also?

I think some representations of the triangle group in $\SU_2(1,1)$ may help. But how to get such a workable representation?

In the paper [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X00921/1-s2.0-S0012365X00002156/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEL7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDSDuBZc8%2BPVacgTRgt7hwWWC4NcnYwBClydAJNbu5rngIgazMNXbeLnFYInmQ42CwvBIQvG2yrc11P7Lxxh5PqvlIq1QQItv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDKVUTN20OqCrYIHuwiqpBPkV4PIycnBJ6CGiKz%2FJdjydvHvN3T%2FJ0yjJVfaItkdqU%2FWhJjth2%2FnC4PiyFy4wvDGYEOIpWFmJLERhOThjHbgYyqH%2BjKCc0VA%2Fp%2BNWNip1We0JV9EjVtxEvUSfuIX6GVZ4kTePlIFQy7jTFBXirIESkGR21w6z7HK9%2Bvp8Hwwz5t21f0%2BlW4nfJW6xYB18MgEEB4%2FR2pDJYLeZ6vd9P1mDE3OkquPijXNp0p77a5YIju24pPtMPN2LKzgzExhGFujyKAh11M3gOxHoG5wx%2FMVtnkssarLjonrCEWJbebkNG4dZT3crCuw33Y6NWlKtwOpNcZgq0%2FJrIzbbs73ncUbivBT9Sv3dL%2Bj%2FEYPbUOOGRY94TDLkJFvlceGTkwx%2BG6X6%2FmauZxey77OrIHz2SixvbQeI4AgrmUWhkFXaDiqsFX%2BGlENndtGGf%2FmvGibR6rsMYZHLaJmz1YPjrvPOUN%2Fq8gZq9aX7XV5YOlhBPdntSqU6st19ljre0W5P9atNIEhY6EAtBx7u9rl145IprYVOACUICAPxCkHfNfNxlQsvyhY1Er%2BUdF0249WR6Je2ALxUTZrbzSoSmiBabUmOQQerflnV9LJKnR3GYMfSirx1dTrP3cbFJ4CR99kI8sOF83XxcGOza75ij0UZ90XSF40Gbk0C4wDa3toypBFDvqDcODYgFZ88rdJFEZHYuFajqavU%2BlDTFl48VQ6Bt5IndrYrNTylB4xNUr8wqvrBmwY6qQFxa81uTJpoZdv8%2F7dt%2Fv%2FQ7kythXfpGAh4WUTi9BVTrOzp8SfCjriP0h9t8nKjDG8heHDzmT1U4sTV1QsJFWFSHaTPRyN2X9CaT%2BehTYuq95mIUecMB6OhSWzytgsaOxycR5UjD6hQeRAgyZw1gvF0rnx4s7wYfNkFdyBCs9ToQKUNyi5Ts0%2Ba2pmb3W8eAVua8SPa8HzKGsdQRq3%2FwmqgHsBXrgy3cA%2Fv&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20221113T053956Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5Q55AW76%2F20221113%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=19b131ad162270098c0cf06d190c23ce42114abb686bbc09d0d7485059a8f0ba&hash=e1bd9bd019a09a09501697de2b4232b68fe9be5168131cd6f549a89426688d9b&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0012365X00002156&tid=spdf-a771ae01-2bcd-48bb-b87b-e64e1ecfd9df&sid=4ac17af47811284c5f59d09-10900177fcbdgxrqb&type=client&ua=51505c53510459535657&rr=76952b7708328e74) author discussed some of the presentations of triangle groups in matrix groups. But I am not understanding the notation $\PSL_2(\mathscr{L}[\zeta_1, ..., \zeta_n])$ on page 351. Can anyone say what it means?

If anyone suggests some more references in this regard that will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The group $G$ is Zariski dense, so you can't expect polynomial conditions

Comment: Do you have in mind a specific embedding of $G$ in $SU(1,1)$, or do you just want $A$ to lie in some conjugate of $G$?

Comment: @EthanDlugie No, I do not have any embedding of $G$ in mind. Yes, I want $A$ to lie in some conjugate of $G$.

Comment: Two hyperbolic isometries of hyperbolic space will be conjugate if and only if they have equal translation lengths. (In terms of matrices, this means they have equal traces.) So it sounds like what you really need is an algorithmic description of the set of translation lengths of the elements of the triangle group. This sounds like a difficult problem! But perhaps someone can answer it if you phrase it in that way.

Comment: @HJRW Thank you for your comment. Yes this is what I want to know.

Comment: Perhaps it’s also worth commenting this is equivalent (or very close) to the same question for the Klein quartic, which covers the (2,3,7) orbifold. Perhaps someone knows the answer for that surface.